# Move|clone element and remove from original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML markup:

```
<div id="subscriptionbox-1">
    <div class="topbar">
        <span class="title">Express</span>
    </div>
    <div class="bottombar">
        <span class="price">300 bsf</span>
        <span class="link"><a class="button  " href="#">Sign Up</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I need to move and element from one place to another on the DOM and after move it then remove from the original position. This is what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.topbar .title').append('<br/>');
  $('.bottombar .price').clone().appendTo('.topbar .title');
  $('.bottombar .price').remove();
});
```

But the result is not how I want since I get this:

```
<span class="title">Express<br><span class="price">300 bsf</span></span>
```

When I want this:

```
<span class="title">Express</span><br><span class="price">300 bsf</span>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems redundant to use clone() and then remove original.

Try

```
$('.topbar .title').append('<br/>').parent().append($('.bottombar .price'));
```